# User Sign-out: clearing the default Google account does not cause the account picker to show up in Android app

Tags: android, google-api, google-api-java-client, google-api-client, google-app-engine

I followed the below link to implement a "sign out" button in my android app, which uses a Google API client. However, upon connecting the google api again, the user is not presented with an account picker. It looks like the value of her/his original choice is somehow still cached perhaps. I've been trying to figure this out for a few hours.

Any and all ideas very welcome. Thank you.

https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/android/sign-in

```
if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
  Plus.AccountApi.clearDefaultAccount(mGoogleApiClient);
  mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've had many problems using clearDefaultAccount and trying to reconnect as well. Finally I've decided to separate the account selection process by using the [AccountPicker](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/AccountPicker.html) class (which, by the way, doesn't require global permissions in manifest).

So, when the user wants to connect, always show the AccountPicker and then use the selected account to build your GoogleApiClient (see .setAccountName in [GoogleApiClient.Builder](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/api/GoogleApiClient.Builder.html)).

Everything works smoothly now.

Comment: thanks jmart, so you have no idea what the underlying issue may be, i.e. perhaps a known filed bug report with google, etc?

Comment: Nope, I searched but I haven't been able to find anything about it. The only thing I found is many people are having problems with these apis. I guess more iterations are needed on those clients to make them work better.

Comment: thanks, so frustrating with these things, your workaround makes perfect sense but i guess we're firmly in the world now where external APIs will never conform to some minimal standard... we are not talking about obscure functionality here, this is basic sign-out and google is pushing hard their G+ stuff on top of that. Sad but ya, we are all about fast iterations and pushing stuff out these days, i guess better than holding out forever for the perfect product /rant

Comment: Very helpful that you noted `AccountPicker` does not require `GET_ACCOUNTS` permission.

Answer (score 3):

This works for me - use revoke to remove all data in the google client:

```
public void logout()
{
    if (mPlusClient.isConnected())
    {
        Plus.AccountApi.clearDefaultAccount(mPlusClient);
        Plus.AccountApi.revokeAccessAndDisconnect(mPlusClient);
    }
}
```

Afterwards, if you try to login again, you'll be presented an account selector again

Comment: yes this works until it doesn't. it is not reliable and the very same code sometimes works, and sometimes does not.... thanks for your comment though.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Did work for me so far though. Have you found a reliable solution for it? Maybe it did not work in an older version but does now?

Comment: not really, it's on my list though the accepted answer is what i was planning to eventually do. admittedly, i haven't had a chance to test with the latest API so this may have been fixed! i'll spend a bit of time coding this long weekend :)

Comment: OK thanks for the info. I just worked with it the last week and personally, on my own phone, I could not see any problems with that solution yet

Answer (score -1):

You are not being presented with an account picker because you didn't call

`mGoogleApiClient.connect()` after reconnecting.

Comment: thanks for your comment, but that is not the case, my issue is exactly that on a subsequent #connect call I sometimes (quite consistently) get no popup.